# AssertionError when calling put or create in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update my Teachers view in DRF by instead of including the link to the department field, I would display the name of the department. When I added the PrimaryKeyRelated field, I was able to see the department.name but couldnt use update or create within DRF. Is there a way I could change the display without causing the need for the methods or is that not the case?

Error

```
    The `.update()` method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default.
Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `school.serializers.TeacherSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on dotted-source serializer fields.

The `.create()` method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `school.serializers.TeacherSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on dotted-source serializer fields.
```

models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tenure = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} teaches {self.department}'

    # dont need success url if get_absolute_url on create and update view

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('teacher', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

serializers.py

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    department = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source='department.name', queryset=Department.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ['url', 'name', 'department', 'tenure']


class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    teacher_set = TeacherSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['url', 'name', 'teacher_set']
```

views.py

```
class TeacherViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Teacher.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeacherSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]


class DepartmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DepartmentSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried add *related_name* for model Teacher in field foreign key and call in serializers? link to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).